# Regular Expression to divide a string with pipe-delimited into multiple groups

Tags: c#, regex

I'm writing a c# code that divide a string into two different groups. a string is pipe-delimited as example below:

- there could be an empty space between two pipes.
- number of pipes to "5GOdNF7Q5fK5O9QKiZefJEfO1YECcX1w" are fixed; In this case, there are 4 pipes.

  ```
      string value = "122312121|test value||test value 2|5GOdNF7Q5fK5O9QKiZefJEfO1YECcX1w|123456789|123456789";
      const string sPattern = @"What should it be here?????";
      var regex = new Regex(sPattern);
      var match = regex.Match(value);
      if (match.Success)
      {
          var begin = match.Groups["begin"].Value;
          var middle = match.Groups["middle"].Value;
          var end = match.Groups["end"].Value;
      }
  ```

  I am trying to get the output of the code to return as following:

  - begin = "122312121|test value||test value 2|"
  - middle = "5GOdNF7Q5fK5O9QKiZefJEfO1YECcX1w"
  - end = "|123456789|123456789"

However, I'm so new to regular expression, and I have tried to write a regular expression for variable sPattern, but could not produce the right regular expression for it. Could any please help? Thanks.

Comment: Does `5GOdNF7Q5fK5O9QKiZefJEfO1YECcX1w` appear in each string of yours? You don't consider `||` two pipes?

Comment: Any reason `string.Split('|')` will not work?

Answer (score 3):

you should use `String.Split`

```
 string [] sarray = value.Split('|')
```

What that will do is give you the array

```
{"122312121", "test value", "" , "test value" , "2", "5GOdNF7Q5fK5O9QKiZefJEfO1YECcX1w", "123456789", "123456789"}
```

and `5GOdNF7Q5fK5O9QKiZefJEfO1YECcX1w` will be in `sarray[5]`

Comment: Split would certainly work. However, i'm required to write a regular expression in this task. And yes, || is considered two pipes. Thanks.

Comment: This is not homework. This is part of my work for my job, however, I'm so new to regular expression. Thanks

Comment: @Andy the reason I asked is because you said that you're `"required to X"`  Why must you use regex?

Comment: Yeah, my company is already having a system that take in a regular expression to parse a text file; and if i'm having a choice i would use the split function i'm not too familiar with regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a regular expression to match this and want to use a regular expression rather than .Split, you could try this:

```
"^((.*?[|]){4})(.*?)([|].*)*$"
```

or more explicitly:

```
"^(?<begin>(.*?[|]){4})(?<middle>.*?)(?<end>[|].*)*$"
```

This is based on the fact that you said the number of pipes before your long string is fixed (at four).

Your code would then read as follows:

```
string value = "122312121|test value||test value 2|5GOdNF7Q5fK5O9QKiZefJEfO1YECcX1w|123456789|123456789";
const string sPattern = @"^((.*?[|]){4})(.*?)([|].*)*$";
var regex = new Regex(sPattern);
var match = regex.Match(value);
if (match.Success)
{
    var begin = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var middle = match.Groups[3].Value;
    var end = match.Groups[4].Value;
}
```

Comment: I made my option more concise based on Rhumborl's comment.

Comment: @user1775603 still doesn't work unfortunately. I was trying to tweak it for you before with no luck. Test it out at http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx or similar.

Comment: @user1775603: Try this `^((.*?[|]){4})(.*?)([|].*)*$` You need to wrap that repeating group and make it not greedy too.

Comment: looks good now. Maybe just set Explicit Capture on and tag the groups you want: `^(?<begin>(.*?[|]){4})(?<middle>.*?)(?<end>[|].*)*$`

Comment: Thanks for the help, people. Looks good now, and I learned something.

Answer (score 1):

The trick may be to escape the pipe character:

```
const string sPattern = @"(?<begin>[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|)" +
                        "(?<middle>[^|]*)" + 
                        "(?<end>\|.*)";
```

Comment: or a slightly neater `(?<begin>([^|]*\|){4})(?<middle>[^|]*)(?<end>\|.*)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String.Split` and some `Linq` to do what you need

Rough example:

```
string value = "122312121|test value||test value 2|5GOdNF7Q5fK5O9QKiZefJEfO1YECcX1w|123456789|123456789";
string[] split = value.Split('|');

string begin = string.Join("|", split.Take(4));
string middle = split.Skip(4).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
string end = "|" + string.Join("|", split.Skip(5).Take(2));
```

Returns

- begin = "122312121|test value||test value 2|"
- middle = "5GOdNF7Q5fK5O9QKiZefJEfO1YECcX1w"
- end = "|123456789|123456789"

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one:

```
^(?<begin>(.*?\|){4})(?<middle>.*?(?=\|))(?<end>.*)
```